# What type of connector it is?

Tags: connector, identification, plug

Can anyone identify this connector type?

It sticks out of my wall near television area. I suspect it may be some kind of antenna connection, but I'm not sure. Could not find it in any of the antenna connectors listings.

[image]

Comment: For future users searching through questions it would be useful to have a written description of what you see in the question

Comment: It is called a ferrule.

Comment: The attachment to the wire is a ferrule, yes, but the connector is not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the look of the wires, I'd say that they are a speaker cable, and the gold pin is just to make it easier to insert the wire ends into binding posts or the wire clips that many speakers have.  Are there similar wires (with or without the gold pin) elsewhere in the room (or elsewhere in the house)?

Comment: It's true. The cable it self is speaker type of cable, t's written on the cable.  Also I notice this cable stick out in basement near the tv area as well.

Comment: FWIW, a lot of mid to high end speakers don't use connectors. They typically have spring loaded clip terminals that you insert bare wires into. Sometimes you'll even find screw type terminals but that's not very common. The ferrule is just there to keep the wire ends from fraying. Lots of people install speakers without them.

Answer (score 6):

That connector is a single gold-plated crimp-on speaker pin.

The other lead used to have an identical connector, and the pair was plugged into a single speaker.  That speaker was ripped off the wall without disconnecting the wire, and the pin you don't see stayed stuck in the speaker's input terminal.